# Best way to exchange data through the internet

Tags: android, google-plus

Well, I know this question looks subjective, but I'm really new to Android development.

I'm really trying to figure out which's the best way to send an information through internet between apps (in that case, my app in both phones), and if it's possible, send only to google-plus friends.

I don't need the code, just a guide to know where do I have to start.

Any kind of help will be welcome.

Comment: what about http://developer.android.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Parse, you're going to have to tackle g+ Oauth one way or another--that will be hard for you--but the easy-peasy fb/twitter integration will give you some design principles, and you'll love NoSQL.

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

gl hf =]

Comment: Thanks @anthopic, it's good to see that someone wants to help even the new ones like me. I didn't know how to do the question exactly. BUt as I said, I'm really new to this.
I'll study this examples, maybe using twitter integration.